# Is the Fisher Linear Discriminant classifier an ERM?

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

Can the Fisher Linear Discriminant classifier be considered an Empirical Risk Mininisation (ERM) classifier?

I know of a formulation as 2 Gaussians with identical covariance, and another that minimises the within-class scatter and maximises the between-class scatter.